# Rails help finder method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to create a find method. That should find all konkurrencer that have the tid "1 min" or "2 min" and the form is "Nyhedsbrev".

I have tried something like this:

```
Konkurrancer.where("tid = ? or ? and form = ?", "2 min", "1 min", "Nyhedsbrev")
```

It doesn't work. It only finds all konkurrencer where the form is Nyhedsbrev.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this works as intended.

```
Konkurrancer.where("tid IN (?) AND form = ?", ['2 min', '1 min'], 'Nyhedsbrev')
```

Other than that, the 'OR' syntac you are trying to use is written like this in SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE column1 = 'foo' OR column1 = 'BAR'
```

Notice that for the 'OR' condition you still need to list the column name again.

Comment: I will approve your answer. Do you know where I can read about rails SQL finder methods. I didnt now know that man can use IN (?)

Comment: You can read about ActiveRecord Query Interface here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

Generally everything you can do in SQL, you can do in ActiveRecord.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Konkurrancer.where("tid = ? or tid = ?", "2 min", "1 min").where(:form => "Nyhedsbrev")
```

You can also use:

```
Konkurrancer.where("form = ? and (tid = ? or tid = ?)", "Nyhedsbrev", "2 min", "1 min")
```

Comment: It is valid SQL, but it is not working as expected. Thank you.

Comment: Sure, it was working too, but without needed effect. I fixed my answer thanks to your comment.

Answer (score 1):

Your SQL is a bit wrong, I think you want this:

```
Konkurrancer.where(
    "(tid = ? or tid = ?) and form = ?",
    "2 min",
    "1 min",
    "Nyhedsbrev"
)
```

Note the second mention of the `tid` column name and the parentheses.